# Calling dojo.onload of an included jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, dojo

I have a complex jsp which consists of other jsps like this:

```
<div id="tab_2_0" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Title"  href="childpage.jsp" preload="false" parseOnLoad="true" executeScripts="true" refreshOnShow="true" style="height:300px;overflow:auto;">
        </div>
```

Now this childpage has an onload function which is not getting called on loading of the main page. The onload functions in the main page are being called.

Is there any way to call onload of childpage as soon as mainpage is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i remember right, the `executeScripts` argument was removed from `dijit.layout.ContentPane` in dojo 1.0.

For such cases you need to use instead the `dojox.layout.ContentPane` which will handle scripts present in the dynamically loaded page fragment.